# VBA text to column with Parentheses as splitter

Tags: vba, excel, text, delimiter

This might be a bit basic, but I basically want to split my data from one string of text into separate cells. Below is the kind of string I am looking to split.

INPUT:   1)VITOL-GUNVORSA, $286.5/mt, 2kt, FOB Rdam, FE
OUTPUT: [So the first row starting in column D is how I would like it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vAWJ.png)

This is the current code I have which allows me to split everything but the numbers from the first name, i.e. `Vitol`. Now my question is, how can add another `OtherChar` so I can also split by `)`?

Thanks.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()


    Dim myRng As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long

    LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set myRng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
    End With


    myRng.TextToColumns _
      Destination:=Range("D2:E2:F2:G2:H2"), _
      DataType:=xlDelimited, _
      Tab:=False, _
      Semicolon:=False, _
      Comma:=False, _
      Space:=True, _
      Other:=True, _
      OtherChar:="-"



End Sub
```

Comment: Can you post some sample output of what you expect? Do you want the `1)` to be in `D`, then `Vitol` in `E`, then `GUNVORSA,` in `F`, etc?

Comment: You could split it twice. First the initial column with the round bracket and then the second column with the code you already have.

Comment: Can you please post a few other examples of the input, and the expected output for each? Will they always be formatted like that? Or will there be other ways to format that you want to break it out?

Comment: ...or run a replace and replace `)` with a comma

Comment: Hi, I have added a picture of how I would like it split. 

Please let me know, and thank you!

Comment: @BruceWayne Yes that is exactly how I want it. 1) in D, Vitol in E, Gunvor in F, and so on.

Comment: @TimWilliams How would the replace command work?

Comment: @BruceWayne Hi, any idea on how I can do this pleasE?

Comment: @BruceWayne Thank you, i'm a complete newbie to this so struggling bit, after I added the code you gave above after With Sheets("Sheet1"), it shows an error saying object required error 424.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through the cells in your range, running a `SUBSTITUTE`, then do text-to-columns.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim myRng As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long

    LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set myRng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
    End With

    Dim cel As Range
    For Each cel In myRng
        cel.Value = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(cel.Value, "-", ", ")
    Next cel

    myRng.TextToColumns _
            Destination:=Range("D2:E2:F2:G2:H2"), _
            DataType:=xlDelimited, _
            Tab:=False, _
            Semicolon:=False, _
            Comma:=False, _
            Space:=True, _
            Other:=True, _
            OtherChar:=")"
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but only problem is that the second OtherChar doesn't work. I want to split the two companies VITOL-GUNVOR into separate cells also. Any ideas or changes I can make to add another OtherChar and make it work please?

Comment: @AmanSinghDhir - Add `myRng.Value = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(myRng.Value, "-", ", ")` right before the `myRng.TextToColumns _` line. Does that do the trick?

Comment: Thank you, i'm a complete newbie to this so struggling bit, after I added the code you gave above after With Sheets("Sheet1"), it shows an error saying object required error 424.